# How to query UITextField wrapped in UIViewRepresentable from a Xcode UI test?

Tags: swiftui, uikit, xcode-ui-testing, uiviewrepresentable

I'm developing my app with SwiftUI, but some elements are still from the UIKit world, e.g. one UITextField with special behavior, that's why I use a `UIViewRepresentable` where the `makeUIView` methods returns a `UITextField`.

When I try to enter text via UI test, I don't succeed in querying the textfield; even `app.textFields` doesn't return anything.

Is this because of using `UIViewRepresentable`, am I missing something?

Comment: You need to make sure you have a coordinator and bindings setup to properly query and set values while using a UIViewRepresentable. It can get messy and often there are easier ways to do it besides using a UIViewRepresentable. Can I ask your reason for using it? Perhaps there's a different way.

Comment: the behavior of the app itself works correctly - I only don't know how to query it from within a UI test. I need to query the elements as that's a password field where I have to enter a value to continue in my UI test flow

Comment: Meybe you should add a screenshot and app.debugDescription() result to this question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation you described. Make sure to set `accessibilityIdentifier` in `makeUIView`. Also bear in mind that if you're setting `isSecureTextEntry` to `true`, you should access it using `app.secureTextFields`